# Site for Computing Forensics questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, forums

Could anyone please suggest a good site, like Stack Overflow, for people working with cyber crime and forensics?

I have a few questions which probably don't belong here. I looked at [Super User](https://superuser.com), but there are only two questions tagged forensics there, one of which is mine. The community there is not very active.

I have some questions also relating to UK statutes, copyright infringement, unlicensed pornography, piracy, etc... anyone know a good place to ask about these topics?

Answer (score 7):

I would check out the **remote-exploit.org** forums.  They will be able to help you out with most technical details of whatever you're trying to do.

If you're snooping around for advice on statues, copyright infringement, and legal matters you should **find a lawyer**. It doesn't matter how knowledgeable **the person on the other end of the keyboard** is, you have no way to prove that the advice they gave you will keep you out of trouble and it **will not stand up as a credible source** should legal authorities demand an explanation of your actions let alone **should you contaminate your evidence**.

Comment: I would have upvoted this, but your boldness scared me away...

Comment: Why is everyone against boldness? Being bold (and writing in bold) is **exactly** the right way to approach life, the universe, and everything!

Answer (score 7):

> I looked at superuser.com, but there are only two questions tagged forensics there, one of which is mine. The community there is not very active.

A suitable alternative might be [Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/); it currently has [52 forensics questions](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forensics) and [30 questions tagged [crime]](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crime).

---

> I have some questions also relating to UK statutes, copyright infringement, unlicensed pornography, piracy, etc... anyone know a good place to ask about these topics?

For these topics, you can try [Law Stack Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/). Please note that it

> is for [educational purposes only](http://law.stackexchange.com/help/disclaimer) and is not a substitute for individualized advice from a qualified legal practitioner. Communications on Law Stack Exchange are not privileged communications and do not create an attorney-client relationship

and check their [Help Center](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before asking a question.

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing your specific question, if it's about a technical aspect of computer forensics, I'd say Stack Overflow would probably be the best site in the trilogy to start.  There's a chance it will get migrated, but at least then you'd know where to ask further similar questions.

If your question is about a legal aspect of computer forensics, I'm afraid no site in the trilogy is a good fit.  Laws are different in every country, so legal questions for any specific country are likely to be closed as "too localized."

Answer (score 2):

A lawyer licensed to practice in your jurisdiction?

I know, it's the usual cop-out answer, but it may be the right way to go, depending on the situation.